# Rendering SVG symbols with text

Tags: css, svg

The following file is a work in progress showing 3 lamps, I am trying to show text centered both horizontally and vertically in each lamp.  I'm not sure whats happening but only the text for lamp3 is appearing and it is not in the correct location.  The other lamps do no show the text at all.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="root">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient y2="0" id="lamp2rim" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#bfbfbf"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#404040"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp2cap" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188" stop-color="#00ff00"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281" stop-color="#018201"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp2spec" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094" stop-color="#ffffff"/>
          <stop offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375" stop-color="#06d306"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient y2="0" id="lamp3rim" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#bfbfbf"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#404040"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp3cap" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188" stop-color="#00ff00"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281" stop-color="#018201"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp3spec" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094" stop-color="#ffffff"/>
          <stop offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375" stop-color="#06d306"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient y2="0" id="lamp1rim" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#bfbfbf"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#404040"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp1cap" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188" stop-color="#00ff00"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281" stop-color="#018201"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp1spec" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094" stop-color="#ffffff"/>
          <stop offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375" stop-color="#06d306"/>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <g id="lamp2" transform="translate(15.0,0.0) scale(0.25)">
        <title>Lamp 2</title>
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(90 320 240)"       fill="#212121" r="167" cx="320" id="lamp2svg_3" cy="240" stroke-width="17.5"/>
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill-opacity="0.64" fill="url(#lamp2rim)" r="160" cx="319.252837" id="lamp2svg_7" cy="239.999045" stroke-width="17.5"/>
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp2cap)" r="150" cx="320.000535" id="lamp2svg_8" cy="240.001698" stroke-width="17.5"/>
        <text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="0" font-size="55" font-family="Verdana" fill="blue">CCC</text>
        <ellipse stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(-47.7626 249.18 168.124)" fill="url(#lamp2spec)" rx="75.675959" cx="249.179609" ry="44.402987"  cy="168.124194" stroke-width="17.5"/>
      </g>
      <g id="lamp3" transform="translate(100.0,82.0) scale(0.25)">
        <title>Lamp 3</title>
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(90 320 240)" fill="#212121" r="167" cx="320" id="lamp3svg_3" cy="240" stroke-width="17.5"/>
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill-opacity="0.64" fill="url(#lamp3rim)" r="160" cx="319.252837" id="lamp3svg_7" cy="239.999045" stroke-width="17.5"/>
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp3cap)" r="150" cx="320.000535" id="lamp3svg_8" cy="240.001698" stroke-width="17.5"/>
        <text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="0" font-size="55" font-family="Verdana" fill="blue">EEE</text>
        <ellipse stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(-47.7626 249.18 168.124)" fill="url(#lamp3spec)" rx="75.675959" cx="249.179609" ry="44.402987" cy="168.124194" stroke-width="17.5"/>
      </g>
      <g id="lamp1" transform="translate(100.0,0.0) scale(0.25)">
        <title>Lamp 1</title>
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(90 320 240)" fill="#212121" r="167" cx="320" id="lamp1svg_3" cy="240" stroke-width="17.5"/>
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill-opacity="0.64" fill="url(#lamp1rim)" r="160" cx="319.252837" id="lamp1svg_7" cy="239.999045" stroke-width="17.5"/>
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp1cap)" r="150" cx="320.000535" id="lamp1svg_8" cy="240.001698" stroke-width="17.5"/>
        <text text-anchor="middle" x="0" y="0" font-size="55" font-family="Verdana" fill="blue">AAA</text>
        <ellipse stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(-47.7626 249.18 168.124)" fill="url(#lamp1spec)" rx="75.675959" cx="249.179609" ry="44.402987" cy="168.124194" stroke-width="17.5"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
```

I really would like an elegant way of centering the text in the parent group.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8kouys3w/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works...viewBox isn't required.

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="root">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient y2="0" id="lamp2rim" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" />
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#404040" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp2cap" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188" stop-color="#00ff00" />
          <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281" stop-color="#018201" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp2spec" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094" stop-color="#ffffff" />
          <stop offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375" stop-color="#06d306" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient y2="0" id="lamp3rim" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" />
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#404040" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp3cap" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188" stop-color="#00ff00" />
          <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281" stop-color="#018201" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp3spec" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094" stop-color="#ffffff" />
          <stop offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375" stop-color="#06d306" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient y2="0" id="lamp1rim" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" />
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#404040" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp1cap" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188" stop-color="#00ff00" />
          <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281" stop-color="#018201" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp1spec" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
          <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094" stop-color="#ffffff" />
          <stop offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375" stop-        color="#06d306" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <g id="lamp1" transform="translate(100,0) scale(0.25)">
        <title>Lamp 1</title>
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(90 320 240)" fill="#212121" r="167" cx="320" id="lamp1svg_3" cy="240" stroke-width="17.5" />
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill-opacity="0.64" fill="url(#lamp1rim)" r="160" cx="319.252837" id="lamp1svg_7" cy="239.999045" stroke-width="17.5" />
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp1cap)" r="150" cx="320.000535" id="lamp1svg_8" cy="240.001698" stroke-width="17.5" />
        <text x="250" y="260" font-size="55" font-family="Verdana" fill="blue">AAA</text>
        <ellipse stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(-47.7626 249.18 168.124)" fill="url(#lamp1spec)" rx="75.675959" cx="249.179609" ry="44.402987"  cy="168.124194" stroke-width="17.5" />
      </g>
      <g id="lamp2" transform="translate(200,0) scale(0.25)">
        <title>Lamp 2</title>
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(90 320 240)" fill="#212121" r="167" cx="320" id="lamp2svg_3" cy="240" stroke-width="17.5" />
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill-opacity="0.64" fill="url(#lamp2rim)" r="160" cx="319.252837" id="lamp2svg_7" cy="239.999045" stroke-width="17.5" />
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp2cap)" r="150" cx="320.000535" id="lamp2svg_8" cy="240.001698" stroke-width="17.5" />
        <ellipse stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(-47.7626 249.18 168.124)" fill="url(#lamp2spec)" rx="75.675959" cx="249.179609" ry="44.402987"  cy="168.124194" stroke-width="17.5" />
        <text x="250" y="260" font-size="55" font-family="Verdana" fill="blue">BBB</text>
      </g>
      <g id="lamp3" transform="translate(200,100) scale(0.25)">
        <title>Lamp 3</title>
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(90 320 240)" fill="#212121" r="167" cx="320" id="lamp3svg_3" cy="240" stroke-width="17.5" />
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill-opacity="0.64" fill="url(#lamp3rim)" r="160" cx="319.252837" id="lamp3svg_7" cy="239.999045" stroke-width="17.5" />
        <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp3cap)" r="150" cx="320.000535" id="lamp3svg_8" cy="240.001698" stroke-width="17.5" />
        <text x="250" y="260" font-size="55" font-family="Verdana" fill="blue">CCC</text>
        <ellipse stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(-47.7626 249.18 168.124)" fill="url(#lamp3spec)" rx="75.675959" cx="249.179609" ry="44.402987"  cy="168.124194" stroke-width="17.5" />
      </g>
    </svg>
```

To recap...there wasn't anything wrong with the original SVG, all that has been done was to change the values for x and y to 250 and 260.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8kouys3w/12/

Comment: I will never understand how you can say that there is nothing wrong with this code.

Answer (score 0):

## clean up code

**Main problem**: all shapes are stacked on top of each other

other problem (fixed):

1. transform="translate(1154.0,0.0) scale(0.25)">
   There really si no reason to transfrom it that far. And scaling should also not be nesasary since you are doing it on all elements.
2. Your svg does not have a viewBox. This means it will not scale.
3. Text: The text displayed was at 0.0 (origin) not any where close to the shapes.

Other (not fixed):

1. WHY WOULD YOU EVER ROTATE A CIRCLE?

   > circle transform="rotate(90 320 240)"
2. Your linear gradients have a stop opacity of 0.988281 Thats a lot of decimals for a opacity really close to 1.

Im going to take a wild gues here and say your code is generated and not coded. So if your having problems with generated code you should fix those issues inside your editor, or learn the basics of svg like viewBox and the text element atleast. That would take less time then posting and answer here.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 110" id="root">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient y2="0" id="lamp2rim" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#404040" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp2cap" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188" stop-color="#00ff00" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281" stop-color="#018201" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp2spec" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094" stop-color="#ffffff" />
      <stop offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375" stop-color="#06d306" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient y2="0" id="lamp3rim" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#404040" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp3cap" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188" stop-color="#00ff00" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281" stop-color="#018201" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp3spec" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094" stop-color="#ffffff" />
      <stop offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375" stop-color="#06d306" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient y2="0" id="lamp1rim" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#bfbfbf" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#404040" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp1cap" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.992188" stop-color="#00ff00" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0.988281" stop-color="#018201" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient spreadMethod="pad" y2="1" id="lamp1spec" x1="0" x2="1" y1="0">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity="0.996094" stop-color="#ffffff" />
      <stop offset="0.703125" stop-opacity="0.984375" stop-color="#06d306" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <g id="lamp2" transform="scale(0.25)">
    <title>Lamp 2</title>
    <circle stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(90 320 240)" fill="#212121" r="167" cx="320" id="lamp2svg_3" cy="240" stroke-width="17.5" />
    <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill-opacity="0.64" fill="url(#lamp2rim)" r="160" cx="319.252837" id="lamp2svg_7" cy="239.999045" stroke-width="17.5" />
    <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp2cap)" r="150" cx="320.000535" id="lamp2svg_8" cy="240.001698" stroke-width="17.5" />
    <ellipse stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(-47.7626 249.18 168.124)" fill="url(#lamp2spec)" rx="75.675959" cx="249.179609" ry="44.402987" cy="168.124194" stroke-width="17.5" />
    <text x="250" y="260" font-size="55" font-family="Verdana" fill="blue">CCC</text>
  </g>
  <g id="lamp3" transform="translate(100,0) scale(0.25)">
    <title>Lamp 3</title>
    <circle stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(90 320 240)" fill="#212121" r="167" cx="320" id="lamp3svg_3" cy="240" stroke-width="17.5" />
    <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill-opacity="0.64" fill="url(#lamp3rim)" r="160" cx="319.252837" id="lamp3svg_7" cy="239.999045" stroke-width="17.5" />
    <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp3cap)" r="150" cx="320.000535" id="lamp3svg_8" cy="240.001698" stroke-width="17.5" />
    <text x="250" y="260" font-size="55" font-family="Verdana" fill="blue">EEE</text>
    <ellipse stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(-47.7626 249.18 168.124)" fill="url(#lamp3spec)" rx="75.675959" cx="249.179609" ry="44.402987" cy="168.124194" stroke-width="17.5" />
  </g>
  <g id="lamp1" transform="translate(200,0) scale(0.25)">
    <title>Lamp 1</title>
    <circle stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(90 320 240)" fill="#212121" r="167" cx="320" id="lamp1svg_3" cy="240" stroke-width="17.5" />
    <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill-opacity="0.64" fill="url(#lamp1rim)" r="160" cx="319.252837" id="lamp1svg_7" cy="239.999045" stroke-width="17.5" />
    <circle stroke-linecap="round" fill="url(#lamp1cap)" r="150" cx="320.000535" id="lamp1svg_8" cy="240.001698" stroke-width="17.5" />
    <text x="250" y="260" font-size="55" font-family="Verdana" fill="blue">AAA</text>
    <ellipse stroke-linecap="round" transform="rotate(-47.7626 249.18 168.124)" fill="url(#lamp1spec)" rx="75.675959" cx="249.179609" ry="44.402987" cy="168.124194" stroke-width="17.5" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I would have added that elements can share the same gradients, no need to boiler-plate those but yeah I'm with you !

Comment: Please keep in mind you are looking at a small snippet of a much larger project, where lamps have individual gradients because they will be controlled independently and colours may vary.  As far as rotating a circle, I believe it is because the gradient is rotated not the circle.

Comment: A viewBox is not required in order for scaling to function

Comment: a viewBox is not needed for scaling function. Its need for scaling the entire svg element!